# How can I dynamically resize a div?

Tags: html, resize, raphael

I found some answers about dynamically doing stuff to `div`s, but none of them did what I want.
I am working with **`Raphael`** js vector library and need a div for the canvas where the objects are going to be drawn. For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #canvas 
            {
                height: 2000px; 
                position: absolute;
                width: 1500px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas"></div>
        <!-- some code here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

In my JS file I did the following:

```
var paper = Raphael("canvas"),
    r = paper.rect(100, 100, 100, 100),
    c = paper.circle(500, 500, 80);
```

Now on my application, the user will populate  the **`canvas`** by creating objects like `r` and `c` I showed above. But the problem is that once an object gets created outside of canvas' dimensions, it will not be show on the paper/canvas.

**I am trying to dynamically enlarge div's size to i.e. height: 3000px, width: 2000px.** I found some answers about `absolute position` but that did not help. Also found about `div overflow`, but this applies to div's parent element. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is resize both the containing div and the paper. In this example I will show your circle is cropped bottom right.

When you click the canvas, it will resize to show your circle is drawn correctly.

See http://jsfiddle.net/kRzx5/7/

```
var paper = Raphael("canvas"),
r = paper.rect(100, 100, 100, 100),
c = paper.circle(500, 500, 80);

// size i want to resize to
var w = 1000;
var h = 1000;

var canvas = $('#canvas');
canvas.on('click', function(){
    // resize container
    $(this).css({width: w, height: h});

    // resize paper
    paper.setSize(w, h);
});
```

In this example I am using an arbitrary size to use, you could keep checking the positions and sizes of each object that gets added, and find the item which has largest value on x and y when checking its bounding box, then resize to this. So paper will always fit the items that get added.

Comment: Oh and you don't really need the position: absolute, I left in what you already had in the jsfiddle example.